# UWP image picker not working for image source

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to get image picker to work, and it does, but for some reason it won't populate as an image.

```
        var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker
        {
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
            SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
        };
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            //Image img = new Image();
            userImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));
            //await ProcessFile(file);
        }
```

and the image is just simply:

```
<image name="userImage" height="500px" width="500px"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't work because the UWP applications have permissions only for some users folders and even you need to browse their files, you need to [specify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) it in the package.manifest of your application which folders you want to access. For simplification, you could create a copy of the file inside the application data folder and get the path from there or set the image source from the stream of the file, but be careful, the second option maybe lead some high memory usage and leaks. You can find how to avoid this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-animations-and-media).

Answer (score 0):

You can set stream as source instead of path.

```
var result = new BitmapImage();

 using (var randomAccessStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{

await result.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);

}
```